# C# .NET: Validator.TryValidateObject - Returns false in unit test but true in library

Tags: c#, .net, validation, nunit

I have a class with a property that is all decorated up:

```
public class AClass 
{
    [DisplayName("A Property")]
    [Phone]
    [MinLength(10)]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [RegexStringValidator("[0-9]{10}")]
    public string AProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I have another class that has a `List<T>` of these classes:

```
public class AnOuterClass
{
    [Required]
    public string SomeOtherValidatableProperty { get; set; }
    
    public List<AClass> SomeClasses { get; set; }
}
```

When I run a unit test to validate the inner class by itself, validation works as expected:

```
[Test]
public void ErrorIfValueTooShort()
{
    var model = new AClass() { AProperty = "123456" };    
    var validationCtxt = new ValidationContext(model);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationCtxt, results, true);
    Assert.That(isValid, Is.False);
}
```

But in practice (i.e. outside of a unit test), somehow validation fails.  Here's how my code looks:

```
public bool IsValidModel(AnOuterClass model)
{
    var validationCtxt = new ValidationContext(model);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationCtxt, results, true);

    if (isValid)
    {
        foreach (var innerModel in model.SomeClasses)
        {
            var innerValidationContext = new ValidationContext(innerModel);
            isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(innerModel, innerValidationContext, results, true);
            if (!isValid)
                break;
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

The outer model validates, but the inner model does not; no matter what value I put in there, it returns `IsValid` is true.  Why would that be?

My unit test is in .NET 6, but the library where this code resides is .NET Standard 2.0. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Testing on .NET Fiddle, it seems working well. https://dotnetfiddle.net/qvAlE1 I suggest you use debugger and see if the foreach is actually being run. Maybe there's no AClass in the model's list at all?

Comment: `if (!isValid) break;` => try: `if (!isValid) return false;`

Comment: And mind that your unit test only covers a portion of your production code. They are not at all equivalent and they should be expected to behave differently.